# why there is additional period after record in DNS

Tags: sockets, networking, dns, network-programming

I found in DNS setting, there is a period after the record. I am wondering what's the reason for this?

For example `test.test.com.`

Answer (score 2):

The 'dot' is the root of the DNS heirarchy and, on some systems, if you don't use it the DNS server thinks it's a record in the current zone and will append it, rather than treating it as an FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name)

G